# CKEDITOR inline and multiple toolbars

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg

I have multiple instances of a CKEDITOR inline on a page.

I want to be able to customise the toolbar for each of these to display different fonts in each of them.

So I have something like the following:

```
CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
var editor1 = CKEDITOR.inline(document.getElementById('editable_476'));
CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = [ .....
];
CKEDITOR.config.font_names = 'Helvetica Nueue/Helvetica Nueue';
```

This works well if I have one, but If I use the same code for another CKEDITOR instance, the font is overwritten.

How do I use different toolbars for different CKEDITOR instances?

Thanks

UPDATE:

```
CKEDITOR.inline( editable_498, {
   toolbar: [
     ['Bold','Italic','Underline'],
     ['NumberedList','BulletedList'],
     ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight'],
     ['Undo','Redo'],
     '/',
     ['TextColor','Font','FontSize']
   ],
   font_names: 'Helvetica Nueue/Helvetica Nueue';
});
```

This throws a syntax error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```

The line is `font_names: 'Helvetica Nueue/Helvetica Nueue';`

Comment: you can customize tool bar on run time.Similar discussion on forums [Ck editor forum](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Change-Toolbar-Runtime)

Comment: For the record, this is throwing an error because of the semicolon at the end of the `font_names` line.  Javascript object properties don't have semicolons after them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use per-instance config:

```
CKEDITOR.inline( element, {
    toolbar: [
        ...
    ],
    font_names: '...'
});
```

`CKEDITOR.config` is something that all instances inherit from. Use config for a specific instance, it'll overwrite global rules from `CKEDITOR.config`.

See the [official configuration guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration).

Comment: I have updated my question, using the code that you supplied.

Comment: No semicolon after `font_names: 'Helvetica Nueue/Helvetica Nueue'`

Comment: Is there a way to set the default font and colour inline?